# How to stop tween of element in CreateJS/TweenJS

Tags: createjs, easeljs, tween, tween.js

I have multiple Tweens in CreateJS/TweenJS:

```
createjs.Tween.get(elem1).to({..});
createjs.Tween.get(elem2).to({..});
```

In timeline, I need to stop one of Tweens.
I tried:

```
var tween1 = createjs.Tween.get(elem1).to({..});
var tween2 = createjs.Tween.get(elem2).to({..});
```

and then:

```
tween1.setPaused(true);
```

But it's returns error that: `.setPaused()` is not a function.

How to stop one of Tweens that I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are referencing the tween correctly?

Here is a quick sample I made to start/stop tweens using `setPaused`: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/cm2we3wk/

It creates tweens like this:

```
var tween1 = createjs.Tween.get(shape, {loop:true})
    .to({x:550}, 1000, createjs.Ease.quadOut)
    .to({x:50}, 1000, createjs.Ease.quadIn);
```

And then toggles them using `setPaused`:

```
// tween1 is passed in as the tween variable.
if (tween.paused) {
    tween.paused = false;
    tween.setPaused(false);
} else {
    tween.paused = true;
    tween.setPaused(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. problem in my case was that I was pausing tween while it was not started, because it's asynchronous function.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to remove the tween with `createjs.Tween.removeTweens(elem)`

See doc here: http://createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/Tween.html#method_removeTweens

Comment: What if you remove the element itself? For example with `elem.remove()`? Would the associated Tween also be deleted?